# Mongoose findOne with variable not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this Mongoose Schema.

```
var mediaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  md5: { type: String, unique: true },
  uploads: {},
  results: {}
});
```

I have string as a variable but it will not find by it. If I insert the string in '' it works but this seems messy.

```
var hash = response.uploads[0].md5hash;
Media.findOne({
          md5: hash
        }, function(err, obj) {
          console.log(obj);
        });
```

What am I missing? The err and obj are both null.

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(typeof hash)`?

Comment: The result is "string"

Comment: Ok. And the value of `hash` is exactly the same as when you run a query through `mongodb` console?

Comment: I think I may have this. It could be to do with the async nature of node (that I am still getting to grips with) - let me check something and report back.

Answer (score 0):

OK - this was my fault. What I hadn't shown here was that the entry that I was trying to findOne on was being inserted just before the query to update it. I had fallen into the async trap being a former PHP person. Rodrigo, thank you for your help all the same.